# Deleting Rows Using Find

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows from the word Modifications to the row before Results. I was trying to use the Find command but I'm not having any luck. Here's one of the many variations I've tried:

```
Sub FindandDelete()
    Modifications = Range("A1:A1200").Find("Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Res = Cells.Find("Results", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Range("Modifications:Results").Delete
End Sub
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: have you tried recording a macro? ... a recorded macro would give you some clues on how to improve this code.

Comment: I tried but all I can get from it are the row numbers and deletion but the rows change each time depending on the data.

Comment: I suggest you declare your variables. Specifically with the `Ranges` you'll then see that you need to use the `Set` keyword to assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FindandDelete()

Dim Modifications As Excel.Range
Dim Res As Excel.Range

Set Modifications = Range("A1:A1200").Find(What:="Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues)
Set Res = Range("A1:A1200").Find(What:="Results", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not (Modifications Is Nothing) And Not (Res Is Nothing) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(Modifications, Res).EntireRow.Delete 'ClearContents '<<edit to delete rows rather than just clear their contents
End If

End Sub
```

This is slightly different using row numbers:

```
Sub FindandDeleteRows()

Dim Modifications As Integer
Dim Res As Integer

Dim lookinRange As Range
Set lookinRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1200")

If Not (lookinRange.Find(What:="Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing) Then
    Modifications = lookinRange.Find(What:="Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
End If
If Not (lookinRange.Find(What:="Results", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing) Then
    Res = lookinRange.Find(What:="Results", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
End If

ActiveSheet.Rows(Modifications & ":" & Res).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: The code keeps giving me an error on the final line. I tried editing it with .Delete instead of .ClearContents and no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Still no luck, it's giving an error on the Res = ... line.

Comment: I've tested and it works fine: just edited the first snippet so it takes account of finding Nothing - as Nothing will throw an error

Comment: All I can say is that it says "Run-Time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set."

Comment: @user3709645 - I've just edited both scripts to take account of find returning Nothing

Comment: are the words being serached for definitely in the _range "A1:A1200"_ of the _Activesheet_ ?

Comment: The first one runs but only selects the cell with Results in it and the second is still giving a run time error.

Comment: are you 100% sure that "Modifications" is in the range to be found?

Comment: Results fell outside of the range. I fixed it but it didn't actually delete the rows just the items in the column from modifications to results. Since results falls around row 20000, is there any way to fix this? I used the first code you provided with the fix.

Comment: if you want to delete then just change `.clearcontents` to `.entirerow.delete`. I'll test and edit.

Comment: It's working now, thank you all for your help especially whytheq.

Comment: @user3709645 (glad it is now working) definitely worth checking out Bernard's answer - the techniques he's included for looping through cells and ranges are really important in vba

Answer (score 1):

2 main reasons why your code wasn't working :

1. You were using "Res" and "Results" to refer to the same variable.
2. You were assigning the values of the cells to the variables, instead of the number of the rows at which those cells were found.

So here you go :

```
Sub FindandDelete()
    Modifications = Range("A1:A1200").Find("Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    Res = Cells.Find("Results", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    Range(Modifications & ":" & Res).Delete
End Sub
```

But this throws an error if the values are not found...

---

So try this more elaborate, but more accurate, technique :

```
Sub SomeSub()

    'Just to stay clean and make sure we're using the proper workbook/sheet
    wb = ThisWorkbook
    ws = wb.Sheets("YourSheet") 'Rename with your sheet's name

    columnOfInterest = 1 'Replace with the number of the column

    'Find the last row of that column
    last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnOfInterest).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop from the first row to the last...
    For x = 1 To last
        'And stop at the first thing that resembles "Results"...
        If ws.Cells(x, columnOfInterest) Like "*Results*" Then
            Res = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    'Loop from the first row to the last...
    For x = 1 To last
        'And stop at the first thing that resembles "Modifications"...
        If ws.Cells(x, columnOfInterest) Like "*Modifications*" Then
            Modif = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    If Res > 0 And Modif > 0 And Res > Modif Then
        'Loop from "Results" to "Modifications" (backwards, indeed) to delete the rows
        For x = Res To Modif Step -1
            ws.Rows(x).Delete
        Next x
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First answer was deleting every row that had "Modifications" in it before the "Results" line.

Comment: your current answer will error if "modifications" or "results" are not present?

Comment: Very true, may go back to a slightly different "previous answer"

Comment: (+1 I liked the original and seems like a shame to lose it)